# How to skip transparent pixels while searching image on the screen?

Tags: java

I'm making a problem, which is going to find a picture on the screen, but the picture I want to search has transparent pixels. For example I would like to find if my screen contains Google Chrome icon, but without checking the background of it. I'm stuck on function, which works on pictures, that has all of the pixels (no transparent), it goes like this:

```java
public static boolean isOnScreen(BufferedImage bi) {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){

                boolean invalid = false;
                int k = x,l;
                for(int a = 0; a < bi.getWidth(); a++){
                    l = y;
                    for(int b = 0; b < bi.getHeight(); b++){
                        if (bi.getRGB(a, b) != image.getRGB(k, l)) {
                            invalid = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            l++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (invalid){
                        break;
                    } else{
                        k++;
                    }

                }

                if (!invalid){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

When I'm checking it with picture that contains transparent pixels it just doesn't work. Is there any fix for this code or any easier method?

Comment: with Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y), true); you can get the color with the alpha value and then use c.getAlpha();

Comment: So I have to check if checking pixel has c.getAlpha() == 0?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you so much. It skips the transparent pixels counting them as valid pixels

Comment: btw if you want to make some automation, like search the image and click on it... you could find Sikuli interesting ... just search "Sikuli Java"